# Unable to create Watson Discovery Service through Bluemix app

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-discovery

[image]While I try to create a bluemix application and then click to create and add a new Discovery service to the same application I get "422 - failed to get credentials service. How do I resolve this ?

Comment: I have the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check to see that your service has credentials? You can do this by going to your service instance in bluemix and clicking on the "Service Credentials" link. If you don't have any service credentials listed then click on the "New Credential" button and once you have new credentials try clicking on the "Launch tool" button again.

If that doesn't work then I'd click the "x" on that error to dismiss it and then look at the service instances dropdown in the top right. Double check to make sure that the selected service instance in that dropdown is the same service instance that you created in bluemix that has the credentials. If it isn't then make sure to select the correct service instance from the dropdown.